# Как убрать из индексации тестовый сайт?

Tags: поисковые-системы, robots.txt

Надо удалить из индекса яндекса страницы тестового домена. Тестовый и основной домен - для одного сайта, поэтому файл robots.txt один. Как в robots.txt указать запрет именно тестового файла?
тестовый домен, к примеру, site-com-ua.1gb.ua, основной - site.com.ua
если Disallow: /, то запрет на основной сайт. А как на тестовый будет?

Comment: robots.txt влияет только на тот домен, на котором он расположен, и если `Disallow: /` прописано в robots.txt домена site-com-ua.1gb.ua, то он не сможет повлиять на домен site.com.ua вообще никак

Answer (score 0):

Сайты обычно в разных папках. В каждой папке свой robots.txt. В папке test должно быть

```
Disallow: /
```

Comment: А где можно почитать про то, что «В каждой папке свой robots.txt» допустимо?

Comment: У меня на виртуальном сервере несколько десятков клиентских сайтов, каждый в отдельной папке `/var/www/site-xxx`. В каждой папке - свой `robots.txt`. В качестве web-сервера работает `nginx`.

Comment: О том, как настраивать `robots.txt` можно почитать в справке Google: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=ru    Там, кстати, сказано, что команды `robots.txt` оперируют каталогами на сервере, а не `url`.

Comment: А, так вы не о тех папках, ну ладно

Comment: Какая у вас структура каталогов (папок) на сервере? Куда указывают директивы root в конфиге nginx?

Comment: Имеет значение не структура папок на сервере, а структура папок на http, которая будет видна пользователям и поисковикам, и то, что вы не пояснили, что именно имеется в виду, меня запутало, в общем проехали

Comment: На http не папки, а url. Вас чем мой ответ не устраивает? Он правильный и работает. Если у вас site-com-ua.1gb.ua в папке /var/www/test на сервере, а site.com.ua в папке /var/www/main на сервере, то в папки /test и /main надо положить два разных robots.txt и все будет работать. И еще - robots.txt никак не влияет на представление сайта пользователям.